# How can I save browser rendered scaled image

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, browser

I've put following code in HTML file:

```
<img src="big_image.jpg" width="300">
```

When I open it in Chrome, I see image scaled to width 300px.

---

### My question:

Is there any way to save that scaled image directly from the browser? Right-click > `Save As` only saves the original big image. I need to save the rendered output, as-is.

Comment: Take a screenshot?

Answer (score -1):

If you want a scaled image to be saved, you need to deliver the scaled image. Setting the width in HTML does not modify original content; it's for display purposes only. And you're still pushing the entire original content to the client (e.g. eating more bandwidth, consuming more client resources).

Comment: Thank you for answer. But, I need to save rendered output because I'm trying to compare some quality metrics of such browser rendered, scaled images. Only idea I have is to take a screenshot and save as uncompressed PNG.

Comment: Right - the browser isn't going to help you in that case.